# How to capture anything POSTed to a PHP script, even if it's improperly formatted?

Tags: php, post

For example, properly formatted would look something like this (I just did a var_dump on incoming POST request):

`array(1) {
  ["fred"]=>
  string(6) "barney"
}`

But what if I sent badly formatted/mangled data, like the naked string "test"?

This is what I'm trying to capture. I'm sending it with the postman chrome extension. My script dumps all of POST into a log file, but since it's just the word "test", it doesn't show up. How would I capture this and all other cases of data sent to my script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `php://input` stream to get the data you want.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

This is the prefered method instead of using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, because:

> it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Example: `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: I'm just debugging; in production, I'm sure php://input would be better; even the PHP site says so. I just needed a quick dump of an incoming POST once. I figured out how to turn HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA on and it worked. file_get_contents('php://input') returned an empty string.